# How to import image files to database on button click in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to move **all** the image files in the folder called **Uploads** to database table.i've tried following things to do so.but it is not working neither i am getting any error.Please help me with this

here is my contoller action method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public bool Upload(int? id)
    {
        try
        {
            //Path of the images in the upload folder
            var fullpath = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"));
            List<string> fullPath = new List<string>();
            foreach (var path in fullPath) 
            {
                db.Execute("ImportImage"); //stored procedure
            }
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }

    }
```

here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Document", FormMethod.Post))
                            {
                                <input type="button" value="Upload Image" id="uploadImg" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            }

    <script>
        $("#uploadImg").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                'url': "@Url.Action("Upload", "Document")",
                'type': "POST"
                })
        });
    </script>
```

here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ImportImage (
   @ImageFolderPath NVARCHAR (1000)
   )
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Path2OutFile NVARCHAR (2000);
   DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR (2000);
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   SET @Path2OutFile = CONCAT (
         @ImageFolderPath
         ,'C:\Users\HP\source\repos\ClickLockDB2\EAStarter\Uploads'
         );
   SET @tsql = 'insert into ImagesScanned (ImagesScannedId, DocumentId, ScanPage) ' +
               ' SELECT * ' + 
               'FROM Openrowset( Bulk ' + '''' + @Path2OutFile + '''' + ', Single_Blob) as img'
   EXEC (@tsql)
   SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

my table in which i want to move that images
Model

```
public partial class ImagesScanned  
{
    public int ImagesScannedId { get; set; }
    public int? DocumentId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ScanPage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great! What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Please remove your redundant question which you already asked.https://stackoverflow.com/q/51898505/7073340

Comment: you could play a little with the datatypes, hence, convert images into bytes, then store them into database as varbinary, and do the reverse to read them from your code. so each image would take one row in a table, if you have 50 images, then it'll store 50 rows.. and so on.

Comment: rest of the method is correct or not because when i put breakpoint i am getting fullpath as null and what about ajax